After a request on an api i have a message that tells me: Another exception was thrown: TypeError: null: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
i have this problem, i make an http request on an api, and i am supposed to display a simple message when i have situation = 0 in the response, and it works well but when in the response situation doesn't exist i have this message and my code doesn't execute however I specified that in the response situation may not exist. this is the message i get
Another exception was thrown: TypeError: null: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
So this is what i did:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GamePage extends StatefulWidget {
  String time = "";

  GamePage({
    super.key, 
    required this.mail,
    required this.password,
    
  });

  final String mail;
  final String password;


  @override
  State<GamePage> createState() => _GamePageState();
}
class _GamePageState extends State<GamePage> {
  Future<void> contenu() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/vfetch_app');
    var response = await http.post(url, headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }, body: {
      "mail": widget.mail,
    });
 var reponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
 final String? situation = reponse['situation'];
  if (situation == 0) {
        print('no data');
      
      } else {
        var image_team = reponse['image_team'];
print(image_team)
}
}```


json { "employees": { "employee": { "0": { "id": "1", "firstName": "Tom", "lastName": "Cruise", } } }
Myghtymouse 007 — Aujourd’hui à 04:59
as you can see the variable "situation" doesn't exist here,and i want flutter to run my code if just like in this case" situation" doesn't exist

which line is causing this issue?

You asked this yesterday, and received an answer. Why are you asking again?

I explain it better here si i am coing to répète the prévois one...anď the answer i received doesnt work actually

You can edit your original question to include a better explanation, if that is required. That will make it easier for others to search your question. If the answer you have is not appropriate or doesn't work then say so in the comments to that answer, so that others can see the status easily. All you've done is abandoned a poor question and answer, leaving it to confuse others. You should update that original question, and delete this one.
